# Why does my mesh have a dark outline on one of the edges?

Tags: edges

[image]

[image]

It ruins the look, it appears glitchy[image]

Comment: Hello :). There seem to be multiple issues - colliding faces, double faces and probably flipped normals. If cleaning that won't help enough, you can also [share your .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following these steps:

1. Go in Edit Mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>, Vertex select <kbd>1</kbd>

   [image]
2. Select all <kbd>A</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and select "by Distance"

   [image]
4. With all selected still press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the Normals

This should fix most issues.
You can check if the normals are ok by activating the "Face Orientation" here:
 [image]

One other thing i believe you may have in your object is one or more faces inside the object, those you could find by selecting some of the outside faces, then pressing <kbd>H</kbd> to hide them. Allowing you to look inside the object you then can select and delete the faces inside the object with <kbd>X</kbd>, "Faces". Afterwards just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide all again.

Should there be still issues, please leave a comment and eventually update the question with a picture pointing it out.

Comment: Perfect. It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:-
Go into edit mode, select all, search remove doubles using spacebar and use it, ande then press ctrl+N while still everything selected.  Hope that works

Comment: I can't find 'remove doubles'.

Comment: You may be able to find it in tabs made around the screen then